# Need help on understanding a singleton pattern

Tags: c++, singleton

can someone explain me this code?

```
class S
{
    public:
      static S& getInstance()
        {
            static S    instance;
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        S() {}
        S(S const&);              // Don't Implement.
        void operator=(S const&); // Don't implement
};
```

What I understood is : 
getInstance is a static method that will return a reference to the instance, but where is this instance created ? I don't see any new S(); so..

Comment: It's created right here: `static S instance;` - you don't need `new` to create an object.

Comment: static variable in function created when first call and exist until program ends;

Comment: Will this create a new instance each time I call getInstance? I don't get it

Comment: @MaxenceHenneron No, it doesn't. You should read a C++ book in order to have an idea about the meaning of `static` in this context.

Comment: it's not because it static - it's because you don't use a pointer in the declaration - you ask for the object itself. alt you can do: static S* instance - and then you'll have to create it with 'new'

Comment: @alexolut no, it's created before `main()` is called.

Comment: @H2CO3 you are wrong http://ideone.com/PQAYXT

Comment: Oh I get it now, sorry I was a bit confused with the pointers. I'm going to learn more about the static keyword for now. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @alexolut 1. I wrote "created", not "initialized". 2. do you **really** think that a specific compiler on a specific platform counts as a reference implementation? Also, google the "as-if rule". (IOW, you would be right if the object were **explicitly initialized;** apparently, the compiler over IDEone doesn't differentiate between definitions with or without initialization in this aspect.)

Comment: As far as I know, function-local objects/variables are zero-initialized on start up and then properly initialized when the function is called.

Comment: @olevegard Yes. The relevant quote from the C++11 standard (6.7.4): "The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
duration (3.7.2) is performed before any other initialization takes place. Constant initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static storage duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first entered."

Comment: (cont.: "An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization.")

Comment: @H2CO3 can you show me which implementation of C++ compiler call C's constructor before main() in my example code?

Comment: @H2CO3 i think in a terminology of C++ that variable is not created until it's constructor called (if we have one or more).

Comment: @alexolut there's a difference between actual behavior, observable behavior and abstract behavior. These can differ and they do actually differ in actual implementations.

Comment: @H2CO3 what type of behavior you mean, when says that the object is created before calling main ()? Is this the type of interest to the topic starter?

Comment: @alexolut No, that's why I was referring to the difference between actual and abstract behavior. In other words, you should have written "initialized" instead of "created" in your first comment (which I intended to correct).

Comment: @H2CO3 can we access this "un-initialized" variable? What you mean when saying "creation"? Is it memory allocation or something else?

Comment: @alexolut No, we can't access it. Yes, I was referring to storage allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block-scope entity with static storage duration (in your case the `static S instance;`) is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration.  Before C++11, this is not thread-safe (however, certain compilers do offer options to enforce thread-safe).  As for C++11, the standard states that "If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization."

Comment: "is initialized the first time control passes its initialization" - if it has an explicit initialization. Nevertheless, it's always zero-initialized before every other kind of initialization.

Comment: @H2CO3  Thanks for the comment.  Yes, zero-initialization always takes place first.

Comment: @H2CO3  `instance` will be "default-initialized" (calling the default constructor) the first time control passes through its declaration.  What do you mean by "if it has an explicit initialization"?

Comment: That's true: the constructor is called when the initialization is executed for the first time. However, in my read of the standard ([see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498610/need-help-on-understanding-a-singleton-pattern/21498725?noredirect=1#comment32453792_21498610)), this does not mean that the object is not allocated well before its initialization.

Comment: @H2CO3  Ah yes.  The storage for entities with static storage duration `last for the duration of the program`.  This is true for `instance`, and `instance` is considered `initialized` upon the completion of its default-initialization.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think happens.